# How to create a comma delimiter while reading from a vector?

Tags: c++

I have two string vectors `readData` and `commaSep`. I want to read from vector `readData` and whenever I encounter a comma (,) I want to insert that data into `commaSep` without the comma. In my program `readData` has values like "`xyz,22,pqr`". My getline statement is wrong so suggest me something.

```
vector<string> readData;  // has string values with ',' separation
vector<string> commaSep;  // insert them in this vector
string temp;
for (int i = 0; i < readData.size(); i++) {
  getline(readData[i], temp, ',');
  commaSep.push_back({temp});
  getline(readData[i], temp, ',');
  commaSep.push_back({temp});
  getline(readData[i], temp, '\n');
  commaSep.push_back({temp});
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::stringstream`.

Comment: What's "wrong" about it? Explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Your answer solves my problem.How do I select your comment as answer